# How to create a personally hosted package registry like bower

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower, package-managers

I'm looking to create a package registry for components or add-ons for the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/), where one would be able to:

- View / search packages on a website
- Upload new packages (components) to the registry
- Download packages from the registry

It would almost be a replica of the [Bower registry](http://bower.io/). There would be a nice front-end for viewing and searching the available components inside of the registry. And a CLI would be necessary for downloading and uploading the packages/components from and to the registry.The registry could link to git/github repos just like bower.

Basically I'm asking how does Bower work, how does it store all of the packages? how does the CLI download the package for the github repo? And how can I replicate it for my own personal use?

Ideally I would like to write the whole thing in NodeJS + MongoDB + AngularJs.

Answer (score 0):

Bower uses your repo Git tags to manage module versioning, it doesn't store the code like npm does. Each time you push a new Tag to GitHub it becomes available as a version for your Bower module. Bower simply constructs the tar/zip/git (not 100% sure which it uses) download link for the Git tag.

Bower does have a DB of course to manage users and published modules.

Comment: Probably not obvious but see here: http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register It states "Your package should use semver Git tags.". This is how it determines versions. I could be wrong about the tar/zip part; it might actually clone them with git right?